# pandas で標準入力からデータ読み込む方法

Tags: python, pandas

pandas で標準入力 (STDIN) から `read_csv` のように読み込むこと可能でしょうか？

STDIN を変数に入れて、それを stringIO にして読み込むのは可能なのですが、もっとスマートにやる方法はないでしょうか？理想としては、jupyter 環境でストリーム（標準出力など）を設定して、次に、そのストリームをpandas で読み込むようなことをしたいです。

Comment: Jupyter notebook で、例えば `output = !(cat x.csv)` として `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(output.n))` とするのはスマートではない、という事でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`何らかの PG | python readcsv.py`
のように起動するのなら次のようにするとよいです

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin)
print(df)
```

jupyterで入力する場合ならこんな風にできます

```py
import pandas as pd

stdin = input()
df = pd.read_csv(stdin)
print(df)
```

---

#### 追記

Jupyterで sub-process走らせて結果を取り込むのは次のようにできます

```
変数 = !何らかのコマンド
```

なので, CSVや JSONは次のようにできます (UNIX系の場合)

```py
out = !echo -e "A,B,C\n10,20,30\n40,50,60"
outj = !ip -j addr
import pandas as pd
import io
display(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(out.n)))
display(pd.read_json(io.StringIO(outj.n)))
```

他に, 対象のセルをキャプチャーする方法 (`%%capture result`) もあるけど `StringIO`使うところは同じ

#### 更に追加

PIPE使って sub-processなら, 代入の手間は必要ないが, コードが必要

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = 'ip -j addr'.split(' ')
with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True) as proc:
    df = pd.read_json(proc.stdout)
display(df)
```

Comment: 質問読み返したら, 追記部分 無意味だったようです。とりあえずそのままにしときます

Answer (score 0):

この記事がそれを扱っています。
[【python】io.StringIOは便利なので使いこなそう](https://www.haya-programming.com/entry/2018/07/03/042203)

> ```
> import io
> import pandas as pd
>
> txt = """
> number,name,score
> 1,hoge,100
> 2,fuga,200
> 3,piyo,300
> """
>
> df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), index_col="number")
> print(df)
> ```

他にはjsonの読み出しですが、こちらの記事で`sys.stdin`を直接指定して出来ています。
記事は2.x系の`print df`でしたので下記引用では3.x系の`print(df)`に変えています。
[Pandas data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18495846/9014308)

> ```
> import sys
> import pandas as pd
>
> df = pd.read_json(sys.stdin)
> print(df)
> ```

`read_json`を`read_csv`に変えても問題無く動作しました。

それからこちらはsubprocessで出力したデータをstringIOに変換して読み取るやり方です。
Unix上の例なので試していませんが、承認されているので動作するでしょう。
[Input for read_csv pandas function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46568988/9014308)

> ```
> import io
> import subprocess
> import pandas
>
> cmd = ('cat', '/tmp/csvfile')
> process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
> csv = io.StringIO()
> for line in process.stdout:
>     csv.write(line.decode().strip('"\n') + '\n')
> csv.seek(0)
> data = pandas.read_csv(csv, index_col=0)
> csv.close()
> ```